# Apache access log files printing only vhost_combined

Tags: apache, tomcat

In my apache webserver log files directory ;  I can see only two files : error.log and other_vhosts_access.log . Whenever anyone access the website; for every access request only one word vhost_combined is printed in other_vhosts_access.log.

Hence other_vhosts_access.log is filled with only one word vhost_combined !
Any idea what could be going wrong !

Comment: Could you paste a part of the log?

Comment: What are the values of the `CustomLog` and `LogLevel` directives in the Apache configuration file(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line such as:

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
```

somewhere in your httpd.conf file before the first VirtualHost entry.

What is happening is that you are attempting to use a format named "vhost_combined" in your CustomLog directive, but a format by that name is not defined, which results in it being interpreted as a format string, which does not contain any formatting (%x) specification, so it is printed just as a string.

By adding the above-described LogFormat line, you are defining the format you want.